# My Router is fast when i reset it but slows down seconds later

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router

I have a Belkin N wireless router which until recently worked perfectly fine. Now i have to reset the router every few minutes, otherwise it slows down to a crawl. What can I do?

I have tried turning the routers firewall off, but it does not make any difference. As far as I'm aware there have been no recent firmware updates.

EDIT: The other devices on my network (laptop and iphone) do not have this problem. I connect to the router using a TP-Link wireless network card and I have already tried uninstalling and installing the driver. Hopefully this will narrow down the problem significantly.

Comment: Are you using P2P? It sounds like you are using P2P and have set the number of connections set too high for your router, so it is getting overloaded and causing problems with it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if there are any new wireless networks in close vicinity? If you live in an area where there are many wireless networks close to each other and those networks use the same channels, then you can experience that as a drastic drop in bandwidth.

I would suggest you use some software to check how many networks there are in close proximity and if there are many, then change the routers channel to one that is less used than the others. If you are in the same situation as me, where there are many (30+) wireless networks close by, then changing the channel will probably not work as all channels might be shared by more than two networks. In that case I would suggest you get yourself a N-type wireless network card and router which will use the 5GHz band instead of the 2.4GHz band to transfer data. Atleast for me, this has rendered that issue dead.

Comment: I downloaded a software which detects wireless networks and it turns out mine is the only one in the area. I'm not too surprised as I live in a fairly rural village. (I edited the problem) thanks for replying anyway

Comment: Yeah, if you live in a place with relatively long dinstances between households, then you will not experience this as a problem in general. Other than trying to swap the router and see if that solves your problem, I am out of ideas.